# bower install on Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, npm, bower, node-modules

I have deployed the app, deployment went successful. But I have found that express was missing in package.json so the app was not working. I have added express to dependency list in package, after deploying again I saw that express was still missing so I added bower.json file with dependencies to run `postinstall: bower install` command in package.json `scripts:{}` list, so that express would get installed on server through bower. But the problem I'm facing now is:

```
To https://git.heroku.com/video-conf.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/video-conf.git'

    $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 1.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.8.6
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > simplewebrtc@2.2.1 postinstall /tmp/build_64e36956fbd8af8e4284fce25bf3edc3
remote:        > bower install
remote:        
remote:        bower localmedia#^2.1.0     not-cached https://github.com/otalk/localmedia.git#^2.1.0
remote:        bower localmedia#^2.1.0        resolve https://github.com/otalk/localmedia.git#^2.1.0
remote:        bower bower#1.7.9           not-cached https://github.com/theshock/atomjs.git#1.7.9
remote:        bower bower#1.7.9              resolve https://github.com/theshock/atomjs.git#1.7.9
remote:        bower express#4.x.x         not-cached https://github.com/strongloop/express.git#4.x.x
remote:        bower express#4.x.x            resolve https://github.com/strongloop/express.git#4.x.x
remote:        bower socket.io-client#1.3.7       not-cached https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client.git#1.3.7
remote:        bower socket.io-client#1.3.7          resolve https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client.git#1.3.7
remote:        bower wildemitter#1.x              not-cached https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/wildemitter.git#1.x
remote:        bower wildemitter#1.x                 resolve https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/wildemitter.git#1.x
remote:        bower webrtcsupport#^2.2.0         not-cached https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/webrtcsupport.git#^2.2.0
remote:        bower webrtcsupport#^2.2.0            resolve https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/webrtcsupport.git#^2.2.0
remote:        bower rtcpeerconnection#^5.1.1     not-cached https://github.com/otalk/rtcpeerconnection.git#^5.1.1
remote:        bower rtcpeerconnection#^5.1.1        resolve https://github.com/otalk/rtcpeerconnection.git#^5.1.1
remote:        bower request#^2.72.0              not-cached https://github.com/mikeal/request.git#^2.72.0
remote:        bower request#^2.72.0                 resolve https://github.com/mikeal/request.git#^2.72.0
remote:        bower wildemitter#1.x                checkout v1.2.0
remote:        bower socket.io-client#1.3.7         checkout 1.3.7
remote:        bower localmedia#^2.1.0              checkout 2.1.1
remote:        bower express#4.x.x                  checkout 4.14.0
remote:        bower rtcpeerconnection#^5.1.1       checkout v5.2.0
remote:        bower request#^2.72.0                checkout v2.78.1
remote:        bower wildemitter#1.x                mismatch Version declared in the json (1.1.0) is different than the resolved one (1.2.0)
remote:        bower localmedia#^2.1.0              resolved https://github.com/otalk/localmedia.git#2.1.1
remote:        bower wildemitter#1.x                resolved https://github.com/HenrikJoreteg/wildemitter.git#1.2.0
remote:        bower rtcpeerconnection#^5.1.1       resolved https://github.com/otalk/rtcpeerconnection.git#5.2.0
remote:        bower socket.io-client#1.3.7         resolved https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client.git#1.3.7
remote:        bower request#^2.72.0                resolved https://github.com/mikeal/request.git#2.78.1
remote:        bower express#4.x.x                  resolved https://github.com/strongloop/express.git#4.14.0
remote:        bower attachmediastream#^1.4.1      ENOTFOUND Package attachmediastream not found
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-100-generic
remote:        npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_64e36956fbd8af8e4284fce25bf3edc3/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_64e36956fbd8af8e4284fce25bf3edc3/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/build_64e36956fbd8af8e4284fce25bf3edc3/.npmrc"
remote:        npm ERR! node v5.11.1
remote:        npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! simplewebrtc@2.2.1 postinstall: `bower install`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the simplewebrtc@2.2.1 postinstall script 'bower install'.
remote:        npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
remote:        npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the simplewebrtc package,
remote:        npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote:        npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote:        npm ERR!     bower install
remote:        npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm bugs simplewebrtc
remote:        npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
remote:        npm ERR!     npm owner ls simplewebrtc
remote:        npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/build_64e36956fbd8af8e4284fce25bf3edc3/npm-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to video-conf.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/video-conf.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/video-conf.git'
```

Even after removing `postinstall` command from package.json and removing the bower.json file totally I'm having the same problem on console when I deploy the app.

Answer (score 0):

Unless bower is installed globally on your server, this might be the way to go:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
}
```